# How to match nothing if a file name glob has no matches

Tags: bash, glob, shopt

I want to loop over all files matching extension `jpg` or `txt`. I use:

```
for file in myDir/*.{jpg,txt}
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

**Problem:** If the directory contains no jpg file at all, the loop will have one iteration with output `myDir/*.jpg`. I thought `*` will be replaced by an arbitrary file (and if no file exists it cannot be expanded). How can I avoid the unwanted iteration?

Comment: If a pattern has no matches, the default/POSIX behavior is to treat the pattern as a literal string, rather than ignoring or removing the pattern.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but note that the braces are not part of the pattern. They are a `bash` shorthand for generating a set of related strings, and as such expand to the string `myDir/*.jpg myDir/*.txt` before pattern matching begins.

Answer (score 24):

Use this to avoid the unwanted iteration:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

From `man bash`:

> `nullglob`: If  set,  bash  allows  patterns  which match no files (see Pathname Expansion above) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

See: `help shopt` and `shopt`

Answer (score 0):

This and a duplicate question both were in context of not just pathname-expansion, but also brace-expansion, and a duplicate asked for POSIX.

The `compgen -G` does `bash --posix` compatible pathname-expansion (no brace-expansion) and... you guessed it: yields nothing if there are no matches.

Therefore write a `bash --posix` function to do it. Brief outline: temporarily use `set -f` to first do brace-expansion (without pathname-expansion) via an echo, then apply `compgen -G` to each result for pathname-expansion. Full function left as an exercise.