# File renaming using regex

Tags: macos, sed, grep, xargs

I have a bunch of files in a folder. Some of them are of the format:

**IMG_YYYYMMDD_junk.ext**

I would like to rename such files into

**YYYY-MM-DD junk.ext**

Example: **IMG_20170214_3939233.jpg** becomes **2017-02-14 3939233.jpg**

So far I was successful in filtering files I need:

**find *.jpg  *.jpeg  *.png | egrep '^IMG_[0-9]{1,8}'**

and I know I need to use sed but I am getting no where specifying and referencing match-groups in my regex for further filename transformation. I know I may have to use xarg later on in the pipe but so far I wasn't successful in transforming each file name just to print it out.

Perhaps, sed is not the best option here.

Comment: You want to have the space in the file name?

Comment: @Inianyes I would like to have a space

Answer (score 2):

With Perl‘s standalone rename command and bash‘s option [nullglob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29438045/3776858):

```
shopt -s nullglob
rename -n 's/.*_(....)(..)(..)_([0-9]+.*)/$1-$2-$3 $4/' *.jpg *.jpeg *.png
```

If everything looks fine remove option `-n`.

Comment: It looks like you need to install Perl‘s `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

A logic in `bash` with *NO* external tools!

You can run the below script from inside the folder containing these images.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do      
    IFS="_" read -ra fileNameList <<<"$file"

    year="${fileNameList[1]:0:4}"
    month="${fileNameList[1]:4:2}"
    day="${fileNameList[1]:6:2}"

    targetFileName="${year}-${month}-${day} ${fileNameList[2]}"

    # Remove this line and uncomment the line with 'mv' if things look OK
    echo "$file" "$targetFileName"
    #mv -v "$file" "$targetFileName"
done
```

The idea is tot split the file name on `_` and store them in array. Then parse the individual digits from the number and form the final name from the combined elements.

Comment: @AstroSharp: Replace the `yourFolder` in the command with the folder you have, i.e. basically from your base folder containing the image files.

Comment: also there are other files that do not match the specified file structure. Those should be left alone.

Comment: folder name has a bunch of _ in it. It breaks the code.

Comment: @AstroSharp: Can you try `cd` into the folder and run ! Check my update!

Comment: thank you. tried, but noticed there are other files in the folder that break it

Comment: I suggest to insert `shopt -s nullglob` before for loop and replace `*.{jpg,jpeg,png}` by `IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9]*.{jpg,jpeg,png}`.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find *.jpg *.jpeg *.png |
  parallel mv {} '{= s/IMG_(....)(..)(..)_/$1-$2-$3 / =}'
```

Or:

```
parallel mv {} '{= s/IMG_(....)(..)(..)_/$1-$2-$3 / =}' ::: *.jpg *.jpeg *.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not really interested in the find command, but in nailing down the `sed` regex:

```
find ~ -type f -maxdepth 1 -name IMG*.jpg | sed -e 's/\(IMG_\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)_/\2-\3-\4 /g'
```

Your example:

```
echo "IMG_20170214_3939233.jpg" | sed -e 's/\(IMG_\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)_/\2-\3-\4 /g'
```

output:

```
2017-02-14 3939233.jpg
```

Comment: ran the first command. there are four files like IMG_* (among others): `find: IMG_20160714_165051.jpg: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: seems like you're missing a hyphen in the find command? Make sure your find is working before piping to the sed command.  You changed the tilde (~) to the directory where you've started the search?

Comment: `find ~ -type f -maxdepth 1 -name IMG*.jpg` using this command. Which hyphen do you think?

Comment: @AstroSharp I'm using the unix find, if you're not then just use the command you had in your original question: "find *.jpg *.jpeg *.png" and pipe that to my sed regex.

Answer (score 0):

A mostly-`bash` solution using its regex-matching operator, `=~`, which supports capture groups that can be accessed via the built-in `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"` array variable:

```sh
for file in *; do
  [[ $file =~ ^IMG_([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})_(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png))$ ]] || continue
  mv "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
done
```